# Conditional combining of multiple datasets/tables based on a value of one variable

Tags: sql, join, merge, sas

I have seen some questions related to my issue, but never exactly the same structure, and as I am quite new to SAS/SQL I can't find a proper way out of my problem.

I am trying for a couple of days to join multiple tables (about thirty)

Basically, my problem boils down to this:

Let say I have 3 tables:

TAB, with 2 variables V1 and V2
t1,  with 2 variables V2 and V3
t2,  with the same 2 variables V2 and V3

I want to join TAB with t1 or t2 depending on the value of V2 to obtain the Full_TABLE

```
TAB
V1  V2
A   1
B   1
C   2
D   2

t1
V2  V3
1   x
1   y
1   z

t2
V2  V3
2   h
2   i
2   j
```

intended result:

```
Full_TABLE
V1   V2   V3
A    1    x
A    1    y
A    1    z
B    1    x
B    1    y
B    1    z
C    2    h
C    2    i
C    2    j
D    2    h
D    2    i
D    2    j
```

Logically, it is a conditional join based on the value of V2:

- if V2=1 then merge TAB with t1
- if V2=2 then merge TAB with t2

I don't know if it is possible to do it automatically,

To give a rough idea, V1 has 30.000 different values, V2 has 27 (so 27 tables t1-t27), V3 has 10 values per value of V2, thus I expect a Full_TABLE of 30.000*10=300.000 rows

So I can manage a semi-automated solution based on V2 and/or V3, but not V1

Any leads in SAS or SQL (or proc sql...) highly appreciated !

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `proc sql` and some SQL cleverness:

```
proc sql;
    select tab.v1, tab.v2, coalesce(t1.v3, t2.v3) as v3
    from tab left join
         t1
         on tab.v2 = 1 left join
         t2
         on tab.v2 = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The data step solution is interesting:

```
data want;
  set tab;
  if v2=1 then do;
    do _n_ = 1 to nobs_t1;
      set t1 point=_n_ nobs=nobs_t1;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  else if v2=2 then do;
    do _n_=1 to nobs_t2;
      set t2 point=_n_ nobs=nobs_t2;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

That's the standard "cartesian join in the data step", just done twice, with an if telling SAS which to do.

Basically, you use `point` to iterate through either t1 or t2 depending on the value of v2.  This could be extended through the macro language if needed to allow for many tables/variable values (similarly to how you would extend the sql solution).

Comment: For medium sized datasets, particularly t1/t2 that fit in memory, this is much faster than SQL - around 10x faster.  For extremely large datasets where t1/t2 don't fit in memory, I'm not sure if it's much faster (I don't have time to test a multiple minute write, and it takes a lot longer as t1/t2 get bigger).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like T1 and T2 are the same table that was split into two based on the value of V2.  Why not just UNION them and then join?

```
proc sql ;
   create table want as 
     select a.*,b.v3
     from tab a
        , (select * from t1 union select * from t2) b
     where a.v2 = b.v2
   ;
quit;
```